# Testing that window.location.replace is called within in a React hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I have a custom React hook that counts down from a given number. At zero, it should redirect to an external URL:

```
const useSessionTimeout = (sessionTimeout, warningDuration, signoutUrl) => {
  const events = ['keypress', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'];
  const [timeRemaining, setTimeRemaining] = useState(sessionTimeout);
  const reset = () => setTimeRemaining(sessionTimeout);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timeRemaining > warningDuration) {
      events.forEach(event => {
        window.addEventListener(event, reset, { passive: true });
      });
    }

    const countdown = setInterval(() => {
      if (timeRemaining === 0) {
        window.location.replace(signoutUrl);
      } else {
        setTimeRemaining(prevTime => prevTime - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      events.forEach(event => {
        window.removeEventListener(event, reset);
      });
    };
  });

  return [timeRemaining, timeRemaining <= warningDuration, reset];
};

export default useSessionTimeout;
```

I have written tests for most scenarios, but I cannot get a test for the `window.location.replace` being called when the timer reaches zero. I am using jest and `@testing-library/react-hooks`.

Using this approach always results in zero calls of the mocked function:

```
delete window.location;
    window.location = {
      replace: jest.fn(),
    };

expect(window.location.replace).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some-value')
```

How can I test that `window.location.replace` is called when the timer reaches zero? What is it about the hook that prevents this approach from working?

Comment: location object is immutable

Comment: @charlietfl Is there another approach you can suggest?